# Retrieving 2 user inputs in a function from anoher function below it

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to be able to echo the value of `$bookName` and `$authorName` from the `addBook` function. Below is my code.

```
function checkFunc {
    echo "$bookName"
    echo "$authorName"
}

function book{
    echo -n "Title: "
    read $bookName
    echo -en "\nAuthor: "
    read $authorName
    checkFunc
}
```

However, when I run the function `book`, the `checkFunc` did not output `$bookName` and `$authorName`. I am aware that if I were to move `checkFunc` function below `book` function, I will not be able to call `checkFunc` since it isn't called yet.

Is there any way to do this if I want `checkFunc` to be able to read in values from the `book` function, and in turn `echo` it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` simply takes the name of the variable to populate as an argument:

```
read bookName    # not read $bookName
```

With your code, `bookName` is expanded, and that value is used as the name of the variable. Since `bookName` isn't quoted, `read` uses its default `REPLY` if `bookName` doesn't already have a previous value. (If you were quoting your parameter expansions as is usually correct, `read "$bookName"` would give you an error if `bookName` didn't have a value.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the $ in the read functions. This works:

```
function checkFunc {
 echo "$bookName"
 echo "$authorName"
}

function book{
 echo -n "Title: "
 read bookName
 echo -en "\nAuthor: "
 read authorName
 checkFunc
}
```